# javascript includes() problems

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var needle = "şebo yağmurlar"

var haystack = {
  "items": [{
    "song": "Yağmurlar",
    "artist": "blah"
  }, {
    "song": "Yağmur",
    "artist": "blah"
  }]
}

var found = haystack.items.find(
  item => 
  needle.includes(item.song.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'))) 
  || needle.includes(item.artist.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'))
```

i have two songs in json. "Yağmur" and "Yağmurlar" but they are searching it like "blah blah yağmurlar" or "blah blah yağmur" or exact "yağmur" "yağmurlar". includes always find "Yağmur" song on my side

```
input => "blah blah yağmurlar"
result => yağmur song
expect => yağmurlar
```

Comment: the elements in haystack.items have no `title` property

Comment: i changed for explain mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your original problem

Make sure the key in `haystack` matches the key you are searching for. Your `haystack` contains the key `song`, but your `find` is looking for the key `title`.

Try this:

```js
var needle = "şebo yağmurlar"

var haystack = {
  "items": [{
    "song": "Yağmurlar",
    "artist": "blah"
  }, {
    "song": "Yağmur",
    "artist": "blah"
  }]
}

var found = haystack.items.find(
  item => 
  needle.includes(item.song.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'))) 
  || needle.includes(item.artist.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'))

console.log(found)
```

## Your updated problem

```
let text = "Hello world, yağmurlar to the universe.";
let search = "Yağmur";
let result = text.includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'));
```

If you want the answer to be false, then don't do a "toLocaleLowerCase":

```
let result = text.includes(search);
```

## Third problem: to reverse the search pattern.

From your comments I think you are trying to say that you WANT there to be no match in the example you provide. (If that is not your intention, please list examples of input, and *what you want* the output to be.)

```js
var needle = "şebo yağmurlar"

var haystack = {
  "items": [{
    "song": "Yağmurlar",
    "artist": "blah"
  }, {
    "song": "Yağmur",
    "artist": "blah"
  }]
}

var found = haystack.items.find(
  item =>
  item.song.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR').includes(needle.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')) ||
  item.artist.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR').includes(needle.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'))
)

console.log(found)
```

Comment: i have two songs in json. "Yağmur" and "Yağmurlar" but they are searching it like "blah blah yağmurlar" or "blah blah yağmur" or exact "yağmur" "yağmurlar". includes always find "Yağmur" song on my side